# How to reduce data table load time?

Tags: ajax, datatables, indexeddb

I am working with data table plugin.  Initially what I tried is to update the data table plugin from a flat text file. The text file would look like below.

```
{
"data":[ 
         {
          "reference":"#VIP-123",
          "application":"Development Aspects",
          "applicationType":"Current Application" 
         },
         {
          "reference":"#VIP-123",
          "application":"Development Aspects",
          "applicationType":"Current Application" 
         }
       ]
}
```

I have a HTML file inside this I am writing JavaScript like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table=$('#app-table').DataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bPaginate":true,
    "bServerSide": false,
    "sAjaxSource": "./data/arrays.txt",
    "deferRender": true,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "reference" },    
            { "data": "application" },
            { "data": "applicationType" },
              ],
            "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
            "ordering": true,
            "bFilter": true
        } );
```

The data table is rendering fine until am not having more than 20,000 rows in the table. As the number of rows will increase in the table then data table took more time to load.

What I notices by going through with several site is that we can reduce the load time by using server side processing and for that I need to go with a server which is not possible in my case because I am rendering data from a flat text file. Then I thought to look for static data storage.

So coming to the problem is using indexedDB can we resolve the performance issue and if answer is yes than can anyone let me know how?

I am able to work with indexedDB but unable to integrate with jQuery data table. I mean what I need to make change in the JavaScript. If we can make server side processing with indexedDB then what will be the script?

Comment: Why don't you use pagination? Even if it didn't take that long to load the data, you'd probably kill most browsers with 20,000 rows of data.

Comment: @jraede, Thanks for you reply. I am already using pagination. tried to load with 30 rows for each page.

Comment: Indexeddb have no problem with scaling. Must be something wrong with usage.

Comment: My Problem Is  "unable to integrate IndexedDB with Jquery data table. I mean what I need to make change in the JavaScript. If we can make server side processing with indexedDB then what will be the server side scripting for indexedDB?"

Answer (score -1):

first read your local file in the following manner:

```
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;


            }
        }
    }
```

Then, use JQuery to parse "allText" into JSON.

Refer [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) for parsing into JSON.

Now, create database using "indexedDB API" as mentioned below:

```
var request = indexedDB.open("<mention_your_db_name_here");
request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
  // The database did not previously exist, so create object stores and indexes.
  var db = request.result;
  var store = db.createObjectStore("books", {keyPath: "reference"});
  var titleIndex = store.createIndex("by_reference", "reference", {unique: true});


  // Populate with initial data.
  store.put({reference: "#VIP-123", application: "Development Aspects", applicationType: "Current Application"});

};

request.onsuccess = function() {
  db = request.result;
};
```

for more details on "indexedDB API", please refer [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)

Comment: It is better to use a sequential read-write transaction than a version-change transaction, for clarity and especially when learning. Populating in onupgradeneeded is possible but is a bad design pattern.